# XSL if else statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to check if a key has a value and if is empty to assign a default value.

```
    <xsl:element name="xtc">
          <xsl:choose name="type">
               <xsl:when test="type!= ''"/>
                 <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
               </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  NULL
             </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
```

Is not really working for me, can someone kindly suggest what could be failing.

**update**
After some digging, I am pretty sure my code should be working, but it is not.

```
        <xsl:for-each select="webservice/parameters/parameter">
          <xsl:element name="{key}">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="{key} = ''">
              <xsl:text>NULL</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But my application is throwing an error,

> The token '{key}' was unexpected.
>   expression = '{key} = ''' Remaining tokens are:  ('{key}' '=' '''') A
>   failure occurred while parsing the style sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace this...

```
<xsl:when test="{key} = ''">
```

With this...

```
<xsl:when test="key = ''">
```

Attribute Value Templates do not apply here, as `test` already expects an expression.

Comment: @J.D But if the test is true, your stylesheet will fail when trying to create `<xsl:element name="{key}">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k why is that =/

Comment: @J.D Because an element's name cannot be an empty string.

Comment: @michael.hor257k in this case, the condition is checking for the value of the {key} and the key contains the element name.

Comment: @J.D I am afraid you are missing the point. If `key` is empty, then your stylesheet will error out when trying to create an element name out of it, and it will never get to evaluate your test or anything else. If it's not empty, then there's no point in testing for it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for your suggestion, would you be able to suggest an edit to my code so that I can check for the value of an element?

Comment: No, because I don't know what you're trying to do or why.